# Bean-Validation: Message interpolation and inheritance

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, bean-validation

We have a set of entities that are annotated with bean-validation constraints using message templates:

```
public abstract class AbstractCar {

    @NotNull( message="{my.package.AbstractCar.someInformation.NotNull.message}" )
    private String someInformation;

    // getters, setters, more stuff
}

public class Roadster extends AbstractCar {
    // ... more stuff
}

public class CompactCar extends AbstractCar {
    // ... more stuff
}
```

The entities are part of another project, they must not be changed. Our task is the user interface which is build using jsf. We would like to present validation messages that are different for the concrete car implementations. E.g. in `ValidationMessages.properties`

```
my.package.AbstractCar.someInformation.NotNull.message = dont show this message
other.package.Roadster.someInformation.NotNull.message = message for Roadster
other.package.CompactCar.someInformation.NotNull.message = message for CompactCar
```

How can we do this? We are looking for a simple solution using the standards but not touching the entity classes.

Btw, we are using payara-5 (Java-EE 8).

Comment: I do not know if it is appropriate for your case, but you could try a custom `MessageInterpolator` - see the Bean Validation spec version 2.0 section 6.3.2.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos We tried that. But in a MessageInterpolator there seems to be no way to get the validated bean class. You can get the `validatedValue`, but nothing else useful.

Comment: Indeed, my thought was actually whether you can define the `MessageInterpolator` on the validator instance you will be using for the form (e.g. as described in the specs `ValidatorFactory.usingContext().messageInterpolator(messageInterpolator).getValidator()`); and that would be possible only if you know what kind of object you will be editing. Anyway I am not using JSF anymore, so just guessing in case it helps.

Comment: Nice idea, Ill give it a try